# How to solve instantiation issue of the application class with dagger-hilt

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have set up dagger hilt correctly but when launching the app it crushes. The error is this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.roomdiexample, PID: 16588
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.roomdiexample.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.roomdiexample.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~oMcb6QXOSnUrrhCyYBR2Cw==/com.example.roomdiexample-ZCL6UuDMUkt4e98K2xdTZw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~oMcb6QXOSnUrrhCyYBR2Cw==/com.example.roomdiexample-ZCL6UuDMUkt4e98K2xdTZw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1244)
```

The Application class is this:

```
package com.example.roomdiexample

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application() {
}
```

I have also added the application class to the manifest. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40.5"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40.5"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'


buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44"
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you have implemented all the dragger dependencies??

Comment: Yes, let me update the question and add the dependencies for you to see

Comment: add these also in your plugins  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' and id 'kotlin-android'

Comment: it hasn't changed anything

Comment: //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44.2"

Comment: also add in project level gradle inside plugins   id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false